# adding accordion feature to divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble how to properly apply an accordion feature to the divs i have. the divs is created from a foreach loop so there are multiple divs each will contain a div with contents so i will need to create and apply unique id so that each div could collapse properly.

View:

```
<div class="list_accordion_toggle icon-minus-sign" id="letter" data-bind="text: Letter"></div>
    <div class="hideThis smoke_hover">
        <span class="h2"><small data-bind="text: Name"></small></span>
    </div>
```

So when i click on the div with id="letter" i would like to have the div with class="hideThis" hidden.

Javascript for multiple divs with content to hide.

```
$(document).on('click', '.list_accordion_toggle', function (event) {
            var togglerArr = [];
            var contentArr = []; 

            $('.icon-minus-sign').each(function () {
                togglerArr.push($(this));
            });

            $('.collapse').each(function () {
                contentArr.push($(this));
            });

            for (var t = 0; t < togglerArr.length; t++) {
                togglerArr[t][0].dataset.target = "#UserList_" + t;
            }

            for (var c = 0; c < contentArr.length; c++) {
                contentArr[c][0].id = "#UserList_" + c;
            }
        })
```

How can i properly bind the accordion feature to the div?

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Pr3Xx/1/

Comment: class name `.list_accordion_toggle` should not start with a `.` in the class attribute

Comment: @ArunPJohny sorry that . was a typo. yes similar to the jsfiddle but i would like all of them open by default and collapsing or expanding divs shouldnt affect other divs

Comment: that is the easiest one http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Pr3Xx/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).on('click', '.list_accordion_toggle', function (event) {
    $(this).toggleClass('icon-minus-sign collapse').next().toggle();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Pr3Xx/)

Comment: I noticed that if a div contains 5 items - clicking on the letter will only collapse 1 out of the 5 items. It doesn't collapse all items under that div?